# url callback function not working

Tags: javascript, html, json, client-side

How can I use the callback function properly cause it's not working.
I want to retrieve my json values from the server to the client side.

For starters I tried this to see if its working.

sample code

index.html

```
<button onClick = "Json()">Click Here</button>
```

my.js

```
function Json() 
{ 
var url = "http://www.sample.com/test.js?callback=displayUser";
var script = document.createElement('script');
script.src = url;
document.body.appendChild(script);   

} 

function displayUser(json) 
{
    alert("working");

}
```

test.js

```
var obj = { "a": "hey", "b": "what?"}
```

but does not return any alert, so I guess it does not proceed to my displayUser function.

Comment: Please show us the code in `test.js`.

Comment: There you go. Sorry about that. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want `displayUser()` called in `test.js`, you have to have code in `test.js` that will call it.  It won't get called just because you put it in the URL.  You would need to code parse it out of the URL and then call it.

Or, alternatively, you can hook up a notification when the script has finished loading and just call `displayUser()` yourself from outside of `test.js` after `test.js` is fully loaded.

To detect when the external script file has loaded successfully and just call `displayUser()` yourself, see [this reference](http://www.ejeliot.com/blog/109).

If you want to get the callback value from the `test.js` script file itself and execute it from within `test.js`, this is the only way I know of to do it:

```
window.displayUser = function() {
    // do whatever
}

var scripts = document.getElementsByTagName("script");
for (var i = 0; i < scripts.length; i++) {
    var url = scripts[i].src;
    // extract filename and callback parameter from the URL
    var matches = url.match(/\/([^\/]+)\?.*callback=(.*?)(&|$)/);
    if (matches && matches[1] == "test.js") {
        // call the callback function
        window[matches[2]]();
    }
}
```

Comment: Ah, I see thanks about that. Now I have to know how to do that.

Comment: I have added two options for you to my answer.

Answer (score 0):

The script that is returned by "http://www.sample.com/test.js?callback=displayUser" actually has to be valid javascript and contain a call to displayUser.

test.js should have a call to dispayUser().